# Author posts by author id using CPT AJAX load more

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, plugins, article

I'm currently using a plugin CPT AJAX load more in wordpress. How can I show posts from only one author by id.

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[cpt_ajax_load_more post_type="post" template="default" posts_per_page="6" button_text="More" button_color="red"]');?>
```

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: WordPress Ajax Load More and Infinite Scroll

https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass "author" attr with your author id as the value.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[cpt_ajax_load_more post_type="post" template="default" posts_per_page="6" button_text="More" button_color="red" author="authorid" ]');?>
```

Below are the default attributes that you can use.

```
// Extact shortcode arrtibutes.
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'nested'                       => false,
    'woo'                          => false,
    'woo_template'                 => '',
    'tabs'                         => false,
    'tab_template'                 => '',
    'filters'                      => false,
    'target'                       => '',
    'filters_url'                  => 'true',
    'filters_paging'               => 'true',
    'filters_scroll'               => 'false',
    'filters_scrolltop'            => '30',
    'filters_analytics'            => 'true',
    'filters_debug'                => false,
    'term_query'                   => false,
    'term_query_taxonomy'          => '',
    'term_query_hide_empty'        => 'true',
    'term_query_number'            => '5',
    'acf'                          => false,
    'acf_post_id'                  => '',
    'acf_field_type'               => 'repeater',
    'acf_field_name'               => '',
    'acf_parent_field_name'        => '',
    'restapi'                      => false,
    'restapi_base'                 => '/wp-json',
    'restapi_namespace'            => 'ajaxloadmore',
    'restapi_endpoint'             => 'posts',
    'restapi_template_id'          => '',
    'restapi_debug'                => false,
    'users'                        => false,
    'users_role'                   => '',
    'users_include'                => '',
    'users_exclude'                => '',
    'users_per_page'               => '5',
    'users_order'                  => 'ASC',
    'users_orderby'                => 'login',
    'comments'                     => false,
    'comments_per_page'            => '5',
    'comments_type'                => 'comment',
    'comments_style'               => 'ol',
    'comments_template'            => 'none',
    'comments_callback'            => '',
    'comments_post_id'             => '',
    'nextpage'                     => false,
    'nextpage_post_id'             => '',
    'nextpage_urls'                => 'true',
    'nextpage_scroll'              => 'false:30',
    'nextpage_pageviews'           => 'true',
    'nextpage_title_template'      => '',
    'nextpage_start'               => 1,
    'previous_post'                => false,
    'previous_post_id'             => '',
    'previous_post_order'          => 'previous',
    'previous_post_taxonomy'       => '',
    'previous_post_excluded_terms' => '',
    'single_post'                  => false,
    'single_post_id'               => '',
    'single_post_order'            => 'previous',
    'single_post_query_order'      => 'previous',
    'single_post_taxonomy'         => '',
    'single_post_excluded_terms'   => '',
    'single_post_progress_bar'     => '',
    'single_post_target'           => '',
    'single_post_preview'          => '',
    'cache'                        => 'false',
    'cache_id'                     => '',
    'paging'                       => 'false',
    'paging_controls'              => 'false',
    'paging_show_at_most'          => '7',
    'paging_classes'               => '',
    'paging_scroll'                => false,
    'paging_first_label'           => apply_filters( 'alm_paging_first_label', '' ),
    'paging_last_label'            => apply_filters( 'alm_paging_last_label', '' ),
    'paging_previous_label'        => apply_filters( 'alm_paging_previous_label', '&laquo;' ),
    'paging_next_label'            => apply_filters( 'alm_paging_next_label', '&raquo;' ),
    'preloaded'                    => 'false',
    'preloaded_amount'             => '5',
    'seo'                          => 'false',
    'repeater'                     => 'default',
    'theme_repeater'               => 'null',
    'cta'                          => false,
    'cta_position'                 => 'before:1',
    'cta_repeater'                 => 'null',
    'cta_theme_repeater'           => 'null',
    'masonry'                      => '',
    'post_type'                    => 'post',
    'sticky_posts'                 => false,
    'post_format'                  => '',
    'category'                     => '',
    'category__and'                => '',
    'category__not_in'             => '',
    'tag'                          => '',
    'tag__and'                     => '',
    'tag__not_in'                  => '',
    'taxonomy'                     => '',
    'taxonomy_terms'               => '',
    'taxonomy_operator'            => '',
    'taxonomy_relation'            => '',
    'meta_key'                     => '',
    'meta_value'                   => '',
    'meta_compare'                 => '',
    'meta_relation'                => '',
    'meta_type'                    => '',
    'year'                         => '',
    'month'                        => '',
    'day'                          => '',
    'author'                       => '',
    'search'                       => '',
    'custom_args'                  => '',
    'post_status'                  => '',
    'order'                        => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                      => 'date',
    'post__in'                     => '',
    'post__not_in'                 => '',
    'exclude'                      => '',
    'offset'                       => '0',
    'posts_per_page'               => '5',
    'scroll'                       => 'true',
    'scroll_distance'              => '100',
    'scroll_container'             => '',
    'scroll_direction'             => '',
    'max_pages'                    => '0',
    'pause_override'               => 'false',
    'pause'                        => 'false',
    'destroy_after'                => '',
    'transition'                   => 'fade',
    'transition_speed'             => '250',
    'transition_container'         => 'true',
    'transition_container_classes' => '',
    'masonry_selector'             => '',
    'masonry_columnwidth'          => '',
    'masonry_animation'            => '',
    'masonry_horizontalorder'      => '',
    'progress_bar'                 => 'false',
    'progress_bar_color'           => 'ed7070',
    'images_loaded'                => 'false',
    'button_label'                 => apply_filters( 'alm_button_label', __( 'Load More', 'ajax-load-more' ) ),
    'button_loading_label'         => '',
    'button_done_label'            => '',
    'container_type'               => '',
    'css_classes'                  => '',
    'loading_style'                => '',
    'id'                           => '',
    'vars'                         => '',
    'primary'                      => false,
    'no_results_text'              => '',
    'placeholder'                  => '',
    'lazy_images'                  => false,
    'archive'                      => false,
    'woocommerce'                  => false,
    'elementor'                    => false,
    'elementor_target'             => '',
    'elementor_url'                => '',
    'elementor_link_label'         => '',
    'elementor_controls'           => '',
    'elementor_scrolltop'          => '',
    'elementor_paged'              => ( ! get_query_var( 'page' ) || get_query_var( 'page' ) == 0 ) ? 1 : (int) get_query_var( 'page' ),
    'elementor_woo_paged'          => ( !isset( $_GET['product-page'] ) || $_GET['product-page'] == 1 ) ? 1 : (int) $_GET['product-page']
), $atts) );
```